# Creating an instance of DynamicDataManager in a SharePoint 2013 webpart throws MethodAccessException

Tags: asp.net-4.0, sharepoint-2013, code-access-security

I'm facing a strange problem in SharePoint 2013 WebPart that instantiates an object of type `System.Web.DynamicData.DynamicDataManager`. It throws the following exception:

> [MethodAccessException: Attempt by method
>   'System.Web.DynamicData.DynamicDataManager..ctor()' to access method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2..ctor()'
>   failed.]   at System.Web.DynamicData.DynamicDataManager..ctor()

In SharePoint 2013 `web.config` the default `legacyCasModel` is set to true by default. When I change it to be false everything is working fine.

I don't know what is the reason behind this. I assume that this is somehow related to the new CAS model of ASP.NET 4 but I don't have a clue why I'm getting this exception when the `legacyCasModel` is set to true.